# Не могу преобразовать систему уравнений для решения методом итераций

Tags: c#, c++, математика, численные-методы

Метод итераций изучил, но система уравнений не подходит, не знаю что нужно делать с ней, помогите пожалуйста) Необходимая точность 0.001. Необходимо решить на языке C# или C++

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Почему не походит? Вполне [симпатичная система](https://ideone.com/i6GuID)...

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void f(double&x1,double&x2,double&x3,double&x4)
{
    x1 = 0.32*x1 - 0.18*x2 + 0.02*x3 + 0.21*x4 + 1.83;
    x2 = 0.16*x1 + 0.12*x2 - 0.14*x3 + 0.27*x4 - 0.65;
    x3 = 0.37*x1 + 0.27*x2 - 0.02*x3 - 0.24*x4 + 2.23;
    x4 = 0.12*x1 + 0.21*x2 - 0.18*x3 + 0.25*x4 - 1.13;
}

int main()
{
    const double eps = 0.001;

    double x1 = 0, x2 = 0, x3 = 0, x4 = 0, y1 = 1, y2 = 1, y3 = 1, y4 = 1;

    for(;abs(x1-y1) > eps || abs(x2-y2) > eps || abs(x3-y3) > eps || abs(x4-y4) > eps;)
    {
        y1 = x1; y2 = x2; y3 = x3; y4 = x4;
        cout << setw(10) << x1 << setw(10) << x2 << setw(10) << x3 << setw(10) << x4 << endl;
        f(x1,x2,x3,x4);

    }
}
```

Comment: Извините, а систему нужно как то решать? просто мне кажется она всё таки дана не в окончательно решённом виде

Comment: Ну так последняя строка вывода и есть решение с указанной точностью!...